# For $1 \le p \lt q \le \infty$ show that neither $L^p(\Bbb{R},\lambda)$ or $L^q(\Bbb{R},\lambda)$ contain the other

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $1 \le p \lt q \le \infty$, and $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Show that $L^p(\Bbb{R},\lambda) \not\subset L^q(\Bbb{R},\lambda)$ and $L^q(\Bbb{R},\lambda) \not\subset L^p(\Bbb{R},\lambda)$ by constructing functions where each belongs to one but not the other.

Hint: You will likely want to handle $q = \infty$ separately.

---

My idea:

After some searching online, I came across this suggestion:

For the first non-inclusion, consider $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{\frac{1}{p}} &\text{if } 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0 &\text{o.w.} \end{cases}$

Here is my attempt to use this function:

Then $\int_{\Bbb{R}}(x^{\frac{1}{p}}d\lambda(x))^p = \int_0^1xd\lambda(x) \lt \infty$

And$\int_{\Bbb{R}}(x^{\frac{1}{p}}d\lambda(x))^q = \int_0^1x^{\frac{q}{p}}d\lambda(x)$ $?= \infty$

I'm not quite sure how to show this. If anyone can help that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

My professor in grad school would say this is about spikes and tails. A ***spike*** is something like
$$f(x) = \frac1{x^r} \chi_{(0,1)},$$
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$, and a ***tail*** is something like
$$g(x) = \frac1{x^r} \chi_{[1,\infty)}.$$
For what values of $r$ is $f$ integrable? For what values of $r$ is $g$ integrable? You should be able to use this to answer your question.

While you're at it, what can you say about the containment

- between $L^p((0,1),\lambda)$ and $L^q((0,1),\lambda)$, when $p<q$?
- between $L^p([0,\infty),\lambda)$ and $L^q([0,\infty),\lambda)$, when $p<q$?

Comment: This is a good way to think about it. Integrable singularities in one $L^p$ space vs not in the other and heavy tails in one but not in the other.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to piece this together. I get the meaning of $f$ being a spike and $g$ being a tail. Am I trying to show that $f$ or $g$ is finite in $L^p$ but not in $L^q$ and vis versa? Doesn't $f$ always approach infinity and $g$ always approach $0$ for all $p$?

Comment: $f$ tends to $\infty$ at $0$ and $g$ tends to $0$ at $\infty$. Maybe I should have a symbol other than $p$ in my definitions of $f$ & $g$. I'll change the exponent to $r$. Say $p=1, q=2$ in the statement of the problem, and consider $f(x) = 1/x^{1/2} \chi_{(0,1)}$ and $g(x) = 1/x \chi_{[1,\infty)}$. Check if $f,g$ in $L^1$ and if $f,g$ in $L^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something stronger (adapted from Exercise 6.6 in [Folland, 1999](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166), p. 187):

> For any given $p\in(0,\infty]$, there exists some $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f\in L^p$ but $f\notin L^q$ for *any* $q\in(0,\infty]$ other than $p$.

Consider functions of the form $$f(x)\equiv\frac{|\ln x|^b}{x^a}\chi_I(x)+\frac{|\ln x|^d}{x^c}\chi_J(x)\quad\text{for $x\in(0,\infty)$}$$ with suitably chosen $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ and intervals $I,J\subseteq(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a measure space $(X, \mu)$ and $1\leq p<q\leq \infty$, we have $L^p(X, \mu)\not\subset L^q(X, \mu)$ if and only if $(X, \mu)$ has sets of arbitrarily small, positive measure and $L^q(X, \mu) \not\subset L^p(X, \mu)$ if and only if $(X, \mu)$ has sets of arbitrarily large finite measure.

I would recommend to not focus on $(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ and prove the above paragraph instead, especially since it isn't that much more difficult.